# I am trying to checked the specific parent checkbox related to child dynamically if i checked to child checkbox in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to check the specific parent checkbox when I click on the child checkbox but unfortuntly all parent checkbox is being checked but I don't want this need to be shown related to on click to child checkbox please help me how can resolve that thanks.

---

[image]

**Html view**

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-root scrolls">
   @foreach ($webMenus as $menu)
   @if ($menu->parent_id == 0)
   <li href="#" class="list-group-item ">
      <label style="width:100%">
      <input id="categories" type="checkbox"
         class=" required_one parent_categories-{{ $menu->id }}"
         name="product_category_id[]" value="{{ $menu->id }}">
      {{ $menu->name }}
      </label>
      <ul class="sub_category">
         @foreach ($menu->children as $submenu)
         <li href="#" class=" list-unstyled">
            <input  type="checkbox"
               class=" required_one  sub_categories"
               name="product_category_id[]"
               value="{{ $submenu->id }}">
            {{ $submenu->name }}
         </li>
         @endforeach
      </ul>
   </li>
   @endif
   @endforeach
</ul>
```

**Jquery**

```
             $(".sub_categories").click(function() {
                if ($(this).is(':checked') == true) {   
                    @foreach ($webMenus as  $key => $value)
                    @if($value->parent_id == 0)
                    $(".parent_categories-{{ $value->id }}").attr('checked', true);
                    @endif
                   @endforeach
                }
             });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intent of approach

I say 'intent' because I am making an assumption which I am not sure whether it is appropriate in your case:

In your code you assign same `id` to checkboxes that repeat. Hence, `id="categories"` would appear multiple times in your DOM and thus not be unique.

### following jQuery-code for both option:

**1.) With your HTML markup (`"categories"` as `id`)**:
(if you cannot modify your HTML markup for any reason)

```
<input id="categories" type="checkbox"
              class=" required_one parent_categories-{{ $menu->id }}"
```

**jQuery**:
(would work in your case without the `">"` parent-child selector as well)

```
$(".sub_categories").click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).parents(".list-group-item")
    .find("label>input") // note the ">" parent-child selector here
    .prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```

**2.) With modified HTML markup (`"categories"` as `class`:)**
(I have assigned "categories" as `class` now, instead of `id` - please advise)

```
<input type="checkbox"
          class="categories required_one parent_categories-{{ $menu->id }}"
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(".sub_categories").click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).parents(".list-group-item")
    .find("categories") // much "cleaner" this way
    .prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```

### Testing the Code:

Following, I tried to reproduce the HTML (for **option 2.**, `"categories"` as `class`) that your server-side code would generate con client-side (DOM in browser) according to your screenshot, so that you can **Run code snippet** here and see whether the result is what you are expecting (Please forgive if I guessed the mark-up wrongly)

```js
$(".sub_categories").click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
  
    // first, iterate DOM up to parent
    // then, iterate DOM down to find the list-group-item checkbox
    $(this).parents(".list-group-item")
    .find(".categories")
    .prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list-group list-group-root scrolls">
  <li href="#" class="list-group-item">
    <label style="width:100%">
      <input type="checkbox"
          class="categories required_one parent_categories-{{ $menu->id }}"
          name="product_category_id[]"
          value="1">
          GIRLS
    </label>
    <ul class="sub_category">
      <li href="#" class=" list-unstyled">
        <input  type="checkbox"
                class="required_one sub_categories"
                name="product_category_id[]"
                value="1 sub 1">
                T-shirts
      </li>
      <li href="#" class=" list-unstyled">
        <input  type="checkbox"
                class="required_one sub_categories"
                name="product_category_id[]"
                value="1 sub 2">
                dsfdsfdsf
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li href="#" class="list-group-item">
    <label style="width:100%">
      <input type="checkbox"
           class="categories required_one parent_categories-{{ $menu->id }}"
           name="product_category_id[]"
           value="2">
           INFANTS
    </label>
    <ul class="sub_category">
      <li href="#" class=" list-unstyled">
        <input  type="checkbox"
                 class="required_one sub_categories"
                 name="product_category_id[]"
                 value="2 sub 1">
                 fghgf
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li href="#" class="list-group-item">
    <label style="width:100%">
      <input type="checkbox"
          class="categories required_one parent_categories-{{ $menu->id }}"
          name="product_category_id[]"
          value="3">
          MAN
    </label>
    <ul class="sub_category">
      <li href="#" class=" list-unstyled">
        <input  type="checkbox"
                class="required_one sub_categories"
                name="product_category_id[]"
                value="3 sub 1">
                gfhgfhgfh
      </li>
      <li href="#" class=" list-unstyled">
        <input  type="checkbox"
                class="required_one sub_categories"
                name="product_category_id[]"
                value="3 sub 2">
                pants
      </li>
      <li href="#" class=" list-unstyled">
        <input  type="checkbox"
                class="required_one sub_categories"
                name="product_category_id[]"
                value="3 sub 3">
                sdfsdfsdf
      </li>
      <li href="#" class=" list-unstyled">
        <input  type="checkbox"
                class="required_one sub_categories"
                name="product_category_id[]"
                value="3 sub 4">
                dsfdsfdsf
      </li>
      <li href="#" class=" list-unstyled">
        <input  type="checkbox"
                class="required_one sub_categories"
                name="product_category_id[]"
                value="3 sub 5">
                dsfdsfdsf
      </li>
      <li href="#" class=" list-unstyled">
        <input  type="checkbox"
                class="required_one sub_categories"
                name="product_category_id[]"
                value="3 sub 6">
                dsfdsfdsf
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

**Note**:
You should use `.prop('checked', true)` now instead of `.attr('checked', true)` (depreciated as of jQuery 1.6)

Answer (score 1):

Use following

HTML View

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-root scrolls">
   @foreach ($webMenus as $menu)
   @if ($menu->parent_id == 0)
   <li href="#" class="list-group-item ">
      <label style="width:100%">
      <input id="categories" type="checkbox"
         class=" required_one parent_category parent_categories-{{ $menu->id }}"
         name="product_category_id[]" value="{{ $menu->id }}">
      {{ $menu->name }}
      </label>
      <ul class="sub_category">
         @foreach ($menu->children as $submenu)
         <li href="#" class=" list-unstyled">
            <input  type="checkbox" data-parent-target=".parent_categories-{{ $menu->id }}"
               class=" required_one  sub_categories"
               name="product_category_id[]"
               value="{{ $submenu->id }}">
            {{ $submenu->name }}
         </li>
         @endforeach
      </ul>
   </li>
   @endif
   @endforeach
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$(".sub_categories").change(function () {
        if ($("[data-parent-target='" + $(this).data("parent-target") + "']:checked").length == $("[data-parent-target='" + $(this).data("parent-target") + "']").length) {
            $($(this).data("parent-target")).prop("checked", true);
        }
        else {
            $($(this).data("parent-target")).prop("checked", false);
        }
    });
    $(".parent_category").change(function () {
        $("[data-parent-target='.parent_categories-" + $(this).attr("value") + "']").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
    });
```

Comment: A/c to your code when I click to parent checkbox then all subcategory is being checked  related to parent category but I need to do that  when I click to any subcategory then  parent category should be checked please can you update your code I can make better understand thank